Can not train keras model with multiple outputs
I am creating a keras model that has multiple differently shaped outputs, as the model.fit method is not allowing me to pass a list or dict of y values. If it matters the model takes a picture of a face and figures out several characteristics and tries to guess the name of the person.
Model definition:
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1024, 1024, 3))

dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8192)(inputs)
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096)(dense_1)
race_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(dense_2)
gender_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(dense_2)
eye_distance_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(dense_2)
name_dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096)(inputs)
name_dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048)(name_dense1)
race = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="race")(race_dense)
gender = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="gender")(gender_dense)
eye_distance = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="eye_distance")(eye_distance_dense)
name_t = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, name="name")(name_dense2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[race, gender, eye_distance, name_t])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss={'race': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'gender': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'eye_distance': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'name': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics=['accuracy'])

Training:
model.fit(np.array([images]).astype(np.float32), ([
                    [races],
                    [genders],
                    [eye_distances],
                    [padded_names]
]))

The Y values I have tried:
[
                    [races],
                    [genders],
                    [eye_distances],
                    [padded_names]
]

and
{
                    "race": [races],
                    "gender":[genders],
                    "eye_distance":[eye_distances],
                    "name":[padded_names]
}

And no matter what I do, it always gives me an error similar to:
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'int\'>"})'})


It seems like you're trying to use multiple outputs in your Keras model, which is a multi-output model. When dealing with multi-output models, you need to make sure that the loss functions and the format of your labels match each output.
The error you're encountering indicates that the data adapter is unable to handle the input format. This typically happens when the input format doesn't match what Keras expects.Each output in the model has a corresponding loss function specified in the loss argument of model.compile().

Each output's label is passed as a dictionary where the key matches the name of the output layer and the value is the corresponding label data.
